# Calculate probability with Brownion Motion

Tags: probability, brownian-motion

Calculate this probability:
$$ P(B_1 <x, B_2 < y) ,
$$
where $B_t$ is Brownian motion.

If $B_1 $ and $B_2$ were independent, it is easy, because this probability would be product of two probabilities, but in this case $B_1$ is not independent with $B_2$ and I don't know what to do.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe you could do this. $P(B_{1}<x, B_{2}<y) = P(B_{1}<x, B_{2}-B_{1}< y-B_{1}) $. And having that $B_{2}-B_{1}$ and $B_{1}$ are independent, you can pass to conditional probability. i.e. $P(B_{2}-B_{1}<y-t |B_{1}=t) $.

Answer (score 0):

It seem to me I found the answer. As I said in the comment, we use the independence, and we will have. $$P(B_{2}<y, B_{1}=t) = P(B_{1}=t)P(B_{2}-B_{1}<y-t|B_{1}=t)=P(B_{1}=t)P(B_{2}-B_{1}<y-t)$$

It remains to integrate up to $x$.

Comment: I don't agree ! Because $ P(B_1 = t) =0$, so the result is 0

Comment: what do you mean with the result is 0? (for one point yes, but when you integrate that will be ok.), Take the density functions instead, and everithing will be ok.

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^{x} P(B_2<y,B_1=t) dt = \int_{-\infty}^{x} P(B_1=t) \cdot P(B_2-B_1<y-t) dt $ What's next?

Comment: Take $P(B_{1}=t)~f_{B_{1}}(t), B_{1}~N(0,1)$. $B_{2}-B_{1}~N(0, 2-1)$ i.e. $B_{2}-B_{1}~ N(0,1)$.

Comment: Sorry B_{2}-B_{1}\~ N(0,1), B_{1}\~N(0,1)

Comment: $ \int_{-\infty}^{x} P(B_{2-1} <y-t) f_{B_1}(t) dt = \int_{-\infty}^{x} \int_{-\infty}^{y-t}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-z^2/2}dz \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-t^2/2} dt$ Can I calculate it better?

Comment: Sorry for late answer. I'm not sure you can. (I'm not even sure about whole technique.) But it seem to me to be correct answer. (No. I'm pretty sure this is the correct answer.) . Use some formulas from here -https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_Gaussian_functions